# Paging Library Callback.OnResult Not Returning Value To Livedata

Tags: android, android-paging, android-paging-library

I wanna to implement jetpack paging library.

everything seems working, after getting response from api (using Retrofit2 and coroutine)
android paging callback is calling his onResult interface.

but it's not returning it's value to livedata in main activity when data received.

What is the solution ?

**ViewModel**

```
    fun getListData(): LiveData<PagedList<DataListModel>> {
        return initializedPagedListBuilder(PagingConfig.config).build()
    }


    private fun initializedPagedListBuilder(config: PagedList.Config): LivePagedListBuilder<Int, DataListModel> {

        val dataSourceFactory = object : DataSource.Factory<Int, DataListModel>() {
            override fun create(): DataSource<Int, DataListModel> {
                return ListDataPageSource()
            }
        }
        return LivePagedListBuilder<Int, DataListModel>(dataSourceFactory, config)
    }
```

**ListDataPageSource**

```
class ListDataPageSource : PageKeyedDataSource<Int, DataListModel>() {

    override fun loadInitial(
        params: LoadInitialParams<Int>,
        callback: LoadInitialCallback<Int, DataListModel>
    ) {
        val apiCall = RetrofitApi.getApiList("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/").create(
            MoviesApi::class.java
        )

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = apiCall.getDataList(params.requestedLoadSize, 10)
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                callback.onResult(response.body()!!, null, 1)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun loadAfter(
        params: LoadParams<Int>,
        callback: LoadCallback<Int, DataListModel>
    ) {
        val apiCall = 
          RetrofitApi.getApiList("http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/").create(MoviesApi::class.java)

        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val response = apiCall.getDataList(params.key + 10, 10)
            if (response.isSuccessful && response.body() != null) {
                callback.onResult(response.body()!!, params.key)

            }
        }
    }

    override fun loadBefore(
        params: LoadParams<Int>,
        callback: LoadCallback<Int, DataListModel>
    ) {

    }
```

**MainActivity**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
       val adapter = ListDataAdapter()
       MainRecyclerView.adapter = adapter

       val viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
       val liveData = viewModel.getListData()
       liveData.observe(this, Observer {
           adapter.submitList(it)
       })

   }
```

**PagingConfig**

```
 companion object{
        val config = PagedList.Config.Builder()
            .setPageSize(10)
            .setInitialLoadSizeHint(10)
            .setEnablePlaceholders(false)
            .build()
    }
```

Comment: Hi, did you ever solve this? I am facing the same issue

Comment: Hi Aerim. i solved this issue by downloading google sample in git. i customized that and now it's working fine.

Comment: In case anyone faces this, my adapter was not implementing PagedListAdapter, after implementing it it all worked fine

Comment: Thanks Aerim. I will take look at this.

Comment: @HoseinHaqiqian Please answer your own question if possible.